# Se repiten imágenes dentro de un listview al hacer scroll

Tags: android, listview

Muy buenas, estoy creando un proyecto en android el cual muestra imágenes y texto dentro de una vista que esta se infla en el `ListView`, al iniciar la carga de la misma, las imágenes correspondiente a cada **item** se cargan correctamente. Pero al realizar el `scroll` hacia abajo y volviendo hacia arriba las imágenes se cargan en los **items** que no corresponden, aclaro que solo es ese problema de la imagen el texto no tiene problemas ese aparece correctamente en cada item.

Las Imágenes ya se encuentran en el dispositivo y estas están accesibles ya que si las muestra. Muestro estas imágenes a través de un `BaseAdataper` y el único problema que tengo es que me repite la imagen en el mismo orden antes de hacer `scroll` hacia abajo.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recursosactivity);
        //category=(Cat_Ref_Fito)getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("objeto");
        int idcategoria=(int)getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("objeto");
        Nombrecategoria=getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("Name").toString();
        listaView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstRecursos);
        mainScreenRecursos=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainScreenRecursos);
        //consultar
        db=new FitoReferenciasdb(this);
        recursosObj=new Rcss_Ft_Sntrs(db);

        if (recursosObj.getRecursosByCategory(idcategoria).size()==0)
        {
            mainScreenRecursos.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fitoproximamente);
        }
        //se llena la lista
        recursosList=recursosObj.getRecursosByCategory(idcategoria);

        RecursosAdapter adapter=new RecursosAdapter(this,recursosList);
        listaView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listaView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        miBar=RecursosActivity.this.getSupportActionBar();
        miBar.setTitle(Nombrecategoria);

    }
```

*Código del Adapter:*

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.i("CREATE VIEW","POSICION "+position);
        View vista=convertView;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        ViewHolder viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
        if (vista==null)
        {
            vista=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.recusos_item,null);
            viewHolder.imgRecurso=(ImageView)vista.findViewById(R.id.imgRecurso);
            viewHolder.txtNombre=(TextView)vista.findViewById(R.id.titleRecurso);
            viewHolder.txtDescripcion=(TextView)vista.findViewById(R.id.descripcionRecurso);
            vista.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else
        {
            viewHolder=(ViewHolder)vista.getTag();
        }


        viewHolder.imgRecurso.setBackgroundResource(0);

        if (Lista.get(position).getImagen_Local_Recurso()!=null)
        {
            File imgFile=new File(Lista.get(position).getImagen_Local_Recurso());

            if (imgFile.exists()){
                viewHolder.imgRecurso.setImageBitmap(getBitmapToView(imgFile.getAbsolutePath()));
            }
            else
            {
                viewHolder.imgRecurso.setBackgroundResource(0);
                Drawable myDrawable=context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fitorecursosa);
                viewHolder.imgRecurso.setBackgroundDrawable(myDrawable);
            }
        }
        viewHolder.txtNombre.setText(Lista.get(position).getNombre());
        //viewHolder.txtDescripcion.setText(Lista.get(position).getDescripcion());
        Animation myRotation= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.rotate);
        vista.startAnimation(myRotation);
        return vista;
    }

    public class ViewHolder{
        protected ImageView imgRecurso;
        protected TextView txtNombre,txtDescripcion;
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmapToView(final String pathImage){
        final Bitmap[] tempMiniature = new Bitmap[1];
                        BitmapFactory.Options bmfOptions=new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        tempMiniature[0] =BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathImage,bmfOptions);
                        tempMiniature[0] =Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempMiniature[0],100,80,true);
        return tempMiniature[0];
    }
```

_La respuesta se encuentra en implementar lo que mensiona este POST que encontre [CARGAR IMAGENES ASYNCRONAMENTE EN LISTVIEW](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/), Y cambiar en vez de que las descargue que las busque en el dispositivo solo es cambiar la parte de la descarga.

Comment: Agrega tu codigo ..

Comment: Listo, ya lo agregue

Comment: agrega un else aquí : 
 if (Lista.get(position).getImagen_Local_Recurso()!=null)
        {
 ...
  } else { 
   viewHolder.imgRecurso.setImageResource(0);
}

Comment: Hola no es la solución aunque trate de hacerlo no funciono decido a que en la memoria se crean objetos temporales de cada vista lo solucione agregando un tag a cada vista

Answer (score 0):

Se soluciona mediante el cargado de imagenes Asyncrono como lo indica en el siguiente [POST PARA CARGAR IMAGENES](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)